# HTML output from RMarkdown is too heavy, I need to divide it into separate subsections

Tags: html, r, output, r-markdown

I have this html output file but when I open it in my browser it takes too long to load and to display the scroll bar at the side. Hence I thought to split the massive file into separate subsections with markdown. How can I do that? Than you . If this can help:

```
title: "my_file"
author: "me"
date: "26/02/2020"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    toc_float:
      collapsed: yes
      smooth_scroll: yes
  word_document: default
---
```

Comment: You can have a look at bookdown (https://bookdown.org/).

Answer (score 1):

**You maybe don't need to divide your document !** As I indicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154819/9959115), a prior explanation that you have to investigate is the sizes of the images or graphics, which are maybe too heavy because of an ultra-high-definition (which is the case by default after most of the computation which resulting in images). Below, I paste my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61154819/9959115) for check the sizes of your images :

> Maybe you'll have to search in the 'image or graphic' part of the code for these 2 cases :
>
> 1- If you indicate size of an image in Rmarkdown at the very beginning of your image-codechunk, check that 'fig.height' & 'fig.width' indicates a reasonnable size, like the following :

```` ```{r name_of_the_chunk, fig.cap="Name_of_fig", fig.height=10, fig.width=8} ````

> 2- the same case is maybe present or necessary in some code that saved the graph or render the image or whatever, so ensure that you indicate for reasonable dimensions ('width' and 'height') in your 'programmatic' way to render the image, if the codechunk don't indicate a size, i.e :

`svg("my.svg", width = 8,height =8)
[code of your graph]`

> maybe height and width are set in `ggsave(file="myfile.svg",device = "svg",width =6,height = 6,units = "cm")
>   [code of your graph]` ... or whatever function you use for generate your pictures.

Excellent day